# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused with 'ant reload' and 'ant start'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, connectexception

Below are the changes i did.....but it is not resolving the issue.... 
Not sure what I am missing

**build.properties**

```
appserver.home=${user.home}/Library/apache-tomcat-7.0.41
$appserver.home}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
appserver.lib= ${user.home}/Library/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/lib
deploy.path=${user.home}/Library/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/webapps
tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

**tomcat-user.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**Build.xml**

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
         <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
         <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
    <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
  </fileset> 
</path>
```

**Stack trace :**
This is the error when doing 'ant reload' ----- adding more test as stackoverflow is not allowing me to post it

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:581)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:852)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask.execute(StopTask.java:44)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: You should probably post the stack trace.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the content of your build.properties?

Comment: yes....its a spring example

Comment: it a example at http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.1

Comment: Also i modified build.prop according to my location for Apache to provide proper paths...it was working before....but once I did ant reload everything stopped working

Comment: There's a space in ```tomcat.manager.url```.  Is this intentional?

Comment: It do not exist in the file...i was facing trouble with posting to stack so added it....